# PHP search item in 2nd level of associative array and delete it

Tags: php, arrays

I have an associative array:

```
array(
    '0' => array(
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'one'
    ),
    '1' => array(
        'id' => 4,
        'name' => 'two'
    ),
    '2' => array(
        'id' => 8,
        'name' => 'three'
    )
);
```

where I want to remove an `item` from the array where its `id = 4`.

**Desired output:**

```
array(
    '0' => array(
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'one'
    ),
    '1' => array(
        'id' => 8,
        'name' => 'three'
    )
);
```

**Question:** What function should I use to find that element and remove it from the array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just roll through the array and then [`unset`](http://www.php.net/unset) the item based on the key.

```
$test_array = array(
    '0' => array(
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'one'
    ),
    '1' => array(
        'id' => 4,
        'name' => 'two'
    ),
    '2' => array(
        'id' => 8,
        'name' => 'three'
    )
);

foreach ($test_array as $test_key => $test_value) {
  if ($test_value['id'] == 4) {
    unset($test_array[$test_key]);
  }
}


echo '<pre>';
print_r($test_array);
echo '</pre>';
```

And the output would be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => one
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [name] => three
        )

)
```

**EDIT** Just noticed your edit to the question that shows desired output of ensuring there are no gaps in the new array. If that is the case, to re-key the array so they are in sequence again, just use [`array_values`](http://php.net/array_values) after the `foreach` in my example:

```
foreach ($test_array as $test_key => $test_value) {
  if ($test_value['id'] == 4) {
    unset($test_array[$test_key]);
  }
}

$test_array = array_values($test_array);
```

And the new output would be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => one
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [name] => three
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2):

this makes a copy of the array, without the undesired element.

```
$new = array_filter($old, function($elem){
    return $elem['id'] !== 4;
});
```

Comment: @JakeGould it never removes it - it only creates a similar copy. Its definitely less efficient than your method of mutating the existing array.